# How to run sql scripts in GitHub Actions

Tags: github-actions

I'm currently building application and want to test on GitHub actions.
I'm using mysql for database and need to insert test data(csv format) into GitHub action's container, but it's not working well.

Here is the steps.

1. Create mysql container. → OK
2. Run script to create table. → NG.
3. Insert test data into table created on step2. → NG.

In every step, there are no errors, but it seems I can't run scripts in step2 and step3.

Please tell me which part of my code is wrong.

Codes here.

ci.yml

```
name: sample-ci

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "main" ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "main" ]

jobs:
  job-with-mysql-8_0:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    services:
      db:
        image: mysql:8
        ports:
          - 3306:3306
        env:
          MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
          MYSQL_DATABASE: sampleDB
        options: >-
          --health-cmd "mysqladmin ping"
          --health-interval 10s
          --health-timeout 5s
          --health-retries 5
    steps:
      - name: setup-go
        uses: actions/setup-go@v3
        with:
          go-version: 1.16
      - name: checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Show Docker containers
        run: docker ps -a
      - name: Show databases for root user
        run: mysql --protocol=tcp -h localhost -P 3306 -u root -ppassword -e "SHOW DATABASES"
      - name: Set up MySQL
        run: sudo /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install enable mysql
             sudo systemctl enable mysql.service
             sudo systemctl start mysql.service
      - name: Run sample.sql
        run: |
          mysql --protocol=tcp -h localhost -P 3306 -u root -ppassword -e "$(cat $(find ./ -name sample.sql))"
      - name: Show created tables
        run: mysql --protocol=tcp -h localhost -P 3306 -u root -ppassword -e "USE sampleDB"
             mysql --protocol=tcp -h localhost -P 3306 -u root -ppassword -e "SHOW TABLES"
      - name: Insert data into user table
        run: sudo /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install enable mysql
             sudo systemctl enable mysql.service
             sudo systemctl start mysql.service
             sh ./.github/scripts/sample.sh
      - name: Check inserted data
        run: mysql --protocol=tcp -h localhost -P 3306 -u root -ppassword -e "USE sampleDB"
             mysql --protocol=tcp -h localhost -P 3306 -u root -ppassword -e "SELECT * FROM user"
```

sample.sql

```
USE sampleDB;

  CREATE TABLE user(
  id INT,
  name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(id),
  UNIQUE(name)
);
```

sample.sh

```
mysql -uroot -ppassword --local-infile=1 sampleDB -e "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/user.csv' INTO TABLE user FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES"
```

user.csv

```
id,name
1,aaa
2,bbb
3,ccc
```

Comment: Is the "**Show databases for root user**" step working? If yes, why are you setting MySQL in the next steps also? Have you tested the same sequence of commands locally and made sure that they are working?

Answer (score 0):

You have a space after `-u`, like `-u user`. But it shouldn't be a space after command args. Try this:

```
- name: Run sample.sql
        run: |
          mysql --protocol=tcp -h localhost -P 3306 -uroot -ppassword -e "$(cat $(find ./ -name sample.sql))"
```

And try to use another port for `mysql` in the workflow

```
jobs:
  job-with-mysql-8_0:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    services:
      db:
        image: mysql:8
        ports:
          - 33306:3306
```

And this:

```
- name: Run sample.sql
        run: |
          mysql --protocol=tcp -h localhost --port 33306 -uroot -ppassword -e "$(cat $(find ./ -name sample.sql))"
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).